# How to set additional_owners to null in Stripe Js?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I'm struggling to set legal_entity.additional_owners to null with stripe js (account class). 
This is to verify Connect account.

I tried the followings but it doesn't work:
- Set additional_owners to null or "": Stripe ask for an array.
- Set additional_owners to [] or on server side (php) set legal_entity->additional_owners = []: On the Stripe dashboard it keeps asking me for additional_owners information.

Basic example:

```
let additional_owners = [];

if (line1 !== "") { 
   let additionalOwner = {
    ....
   }
   additional_owners.push(additionalOwner);
}

let account = {   
  legal_entity: {
       additional_owners: additional_owners
      } 
 }
```

What am I missing? Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got my answer, directly from Stripe team.
The main point is two post with backend are needed.
One that post the js token and one that set additional_owners to null.

Code example (tested):

```
Stripe::setApiKey($this->stripeApiKey);
$account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve($accountStripeId);

$jsToken = $form['stripeToken']->getData();
$account->account_token = $jsToken;
$account->save();

if ($form['hasAdditionalOwners']->getData() === false) {
   $account = \Stripe\Account::retrieve($accountStripeId);
   $account->legal_entity->additional_owners = null;
   $account->save();
}
```

Original answer from Stripe team bellow (in French, sorry for that):

Il est possible de retirer/ou indiquer l'absence des additional owners du compte depuis votre API comme indiqué dans notre documentation : https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-tokens#removing.

La démarche doit être faite depuis votre serveur une fois que le compte a été créé avec les autres informations dans le token du compte. Il y a donc ici trois étapes importantes :

1/ Créer le token du compte, en ignorant la propriété  'additional_owners' si cette dernière est vide.
2/ Créer le compte avec le token.  
3/ Mettre à jour le compte grâce à l'appel API Update account et passez la propriétaire 'legal_entity.additional_owners' à null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the field explicitly to `null` in your backend PHP code, as per the [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#additional-owners).

```
// Indicate that there are no additional owners
$account->legal_entity->additional_owners = null;

$account->save();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be correct if I wouldn't use Stripe Js. But with stripe Js you can't save the js token on your server side and set additional_owners to null at the same time. I tried.

Comment: Ah, ok, yes, account tokens would complicate this slightly, good point. Thanks for posting your answer!